# Using AVSpeechSynthesizer on background

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, xcode5

I'm trying to use this one also when app is on background, Tried to add that in capabilities -> background -> play audio. And also checked that the plist have this line.

But that doesn't work. What am I missing? Can I only play regular audio?

Comment: I had the same issue, check out imihaly's answer on my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183591/avspeechsynthesizer-in-background-mode/19200177

Comment: @nicu wrote that as an answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add on target's info.plist the key "Required background modes" to "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay".
2. Configure the audio session in your AppDelegate:

   ```
   NSError *error = NULL;
   AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
   [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
   if(error) {
       // Do some error handling
   }
   [session setActive:YES error:&error];
   if (error) {
       // Do some error handling
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to import AVFoundation.h

Credits to @nicu