# UIAccessibilityPostNotification in background

Tags: ios, notifications, voiceover, uiaccessibility, uiaccessibility-notification

A blind tester of mine suggested the use of simple vocal notifications instead of the full blown ones, totally useless to them and just wasting battery life. So I thought of employing:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification,"string")
```

for that. Too bad the string is not read while the app is in background as I could test by executing the app in the remote fetch target. Is there some way to trigger just voice notification even in background for VoiceOver users?

Comment: i believe uiaccessibility will only reads the elements visible to the user, but not when the app is in background. Did u try posting the notification in the app delegate app enter background method ?

Comment: Yes, of course and I also checked the command was executed. In fact I was of that idea too, yet my blind tester told me other apps provided voice notifications without showing any alert and I may think of no the way to attain that, short of recording the message and delivering it as a sound.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`AVSpeechSynthesizer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19183591/3825084) in background mode to get your vocal notification and check if [VoiceOver is running](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-options) if it's just for this kind of users.