# Use AVSpeechSynthesizer in background without stopping f.e. music app

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

I'd like to know how to **properly** let my iPhone speak one sentence while my app is in background but then return to whatever was playing before.

My question is quite similar to [AVSpeechSynthesizer in background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183591/avspeechsynthesizer-in-background-mode) but again with the difference that I want to be able to "say something" while in background **without** having to stop Music that is playing. So while my `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is speaking, music should pause (or be a bit less loud) but then it should resume. Even when my app is currently in background.

What I am trying to archive is a spoken summary of tracking-stats while GPS-Tracking in my fitness app. And chances are that you are listening to music is quite high, and I don't want to disturb the user...

Comment: Have you already looked at AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers and similar options?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer myself...

The important part ist to configure the `AVAudioSession` with the `.duckOthers` option:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .duckOthers)
```

This will make playback of f.e. music less loud but this would make it stay less loud even when speech is done. This is why you need to set a delegate for the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` and then handle it like so:

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
    guard !synthesizer.isSpeaking else { return }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try? audioSession.setActive(false)
}
```

That way, music will continue with normal volume after speech is done.

Also, right before speaking, I activate my audioSession just to make sure (not sure if that would really be necessary, but since I do so, I have no more problems...)

Comment: Use this: [.duckOthers, .interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers]. It will restore volume (of Music app, etc) to normal immediately after the spoken part is done.

Answer (score 3):

For swift 3, import AVKit then add

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

Comment: You have to configure the audio session in your AppDelegate

Comment: I already found the solution... I have to set the category but also set the option to `.duckOthers`. Then I need a delegate for `AVSpeechSynthesizer` and set the session not active once it's done speaking...

Comment: AVKit has to replaced with AVFoundation and set "Audio and AirPlay" in background modes is obviously still needed

Answer (score 2):

for swift 4.2 / Xcode 10

unfortunately .duckOthers is no longer available; I managed to make it work like that:

```
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient, mode: .default)
```

Comment: `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers])`

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.0**

```
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let synthesizerVoice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

let str = "String"
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)

let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try! audioSession.setCategory(
    AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
    options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers
)
        
utterance.rate = 0.5
utterance.voice = synthesizerVoice

synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

Comment: Option could be "duckOthers" if user wants to soften the background music or sound.

Answer (score 0):

Background music don't stop and your word sound play even phone in silent mode by this two line of code **before** usual text to speech codes :

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
```