# Text to speech playing when app closed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text-to-speech

How can you make text to speech play whilst the app is closed (in the background)? - Because text to speech is not constant (whereas something like music is), the audio session closes if speech isn't played closed enough together - how can I prevent this?

Comment: If you can re-write this question in a less confusing manner, then I will attempt to answer it.  Your note only makes things infinitely more confusing.  Pretend that you are writing a computer program and everything has to be precise.

Comment: I have changed it now.

Comment: That's an interesting problem.  Well there must be some way to do it because this is exactly how, say, Google maps, works if you have it in the background.  here is a a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183591/avspeechsynthesizer-in-background-mode.  You'll probably get more help if you also include "what have you tried so far" in your question.